# How can I run Python script with commands in C# button

Tags: c#

This is my codes

```
ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
                
ps.FileName = @"C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python.exe";
                
ps.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                
ps.Arguments = string.Format("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\order.py-master\\order.py-master\\order.py -a 999 -b ",this.textbox.Text);
                
Process.Start(ps);
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function that I am using in my project that is called "RunBat" which runs bat files, but can really work on any file extension such as .py as well.

```
RunFile.RunBat("Directory/To/Script.py", true);
```

The way this was possible was by using Process.Start() and setting the path into the base directory, so all you would need to do is input the rest of the directory that leads to the file.

```
public static int RunBat(string currentFile, bool waitexit)
        {
            try
            {
                string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = path + currentFile;
                process.Start();
                if (waitexit == true)
                {
                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
                return 0;
        
            }
            catch
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

The `bool waitexit` is an optional setting to keep the prompt open while it does it's commands. You can turn this off by using `false`.

If this fails to work, and you are trying to run a file that is NOT added as a resource in the code, then you would want to change the  `string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;` to `C:\\`.
What this will do is instead of starting from the base directory of the application, it will start from the C:\ drive, and then you would continue the rest of the directory in `currentFile`.